# Using a private data member in class implementation?

Tags: c++, opencv

Hello this is part of my code in OpenCV library. Infact I have 2 issues.

1) I want to initialise a template class of `vector<Mat> Image[MAX_ITER]`
where `MAX_ITER` is a `const static int` implemented in the class definition. When using a `Image[r]` as below in the class implementation to store images:

```
        ImageSegment::Image[r] = Mat::zeros(src.rows, src.cols, CV_8UC3);
        ImageSegment::Image[r] = tempMerged.reshape(0,src.rows);
```

yields the following error.

```
 Invalid use of non-static data member 'Image'
```

2) I have a private data member `minCluster = 2` initialised in the constructor, but when using `minCluster`  to initiate another data member in the class implementation:

```
    int clusters = ImageSegment::minCluster;
```

I get the following error:

```
minCluster is a private member of 'ImageSegment'
```

I do understand that I use access modifier `public` for `minCluster` in this case to fix my error, but I don't want minCluster to be modified. How do I go about it?
I presume my understanding of the access modifiers is not great and hence I have these issues.

This is class definition:

```
#ifndef ____ImageSegment__
#define ____ImageSegment__

#include <stdio.h>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2/video/background_segm.hpp>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include "math.h"
#include <opencv2/video/background_segm.hpp>

#endif /* defined(____ImageSegment__) */


using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

class ImageSegment
{
   private:
     Mat filterOutput, dst;
     Mat FG, BG;
     float area;
     CvPoint origin;
     Size filter;
     Mat detectEdges(Mat src);
     vector<Point>  approxOuterPolygon(Mat edge);
     vector<int> kmeansSegmentation(Mat src);
     int optimalCluster(vector<int> compactness, int iter, int minCluster);
     void displayImage(Mat src, vector<Point> approxPolygon);
     int minCluster;


  public:
    ImageSegment();
    CvPoint findSegment(Mat src);
    const static int MAX_ITER = 12;
    vector<Mat>Image[MAX_ITER];
};
```

This is PART of my class implementation
Constructor:

```
    ImageSegment::ImageSegment()
    {
          minCluster = 3;
          cout << "\nImage segment obj created\n" << endl;
    }
```

Other part of my class implementation

```
vector<int> kmeansSegmentation(Mat src)
{
//Now run K-Means algorithm to segment image based on colour
//Setup for K-Means Algorithm
Mat samples(src.rows*src.cols, src.channels(), CV_32F);
Mat srcClone;

//Algorithm will run 5 times with 5 cluster values, best compactness will be chosen
vector<int> compactness(ImageSegment::MAX_ITER);

vector<vector<int>> labels(samples.rows);
vector<Mat> centresVector(ImageSegment::MAX_ITER);
Mat centres;
int clusters = ImageSegment::minCluster;

//Building the samples into feature vector of RGB pixel values of src
srcClone = src.clone();
samples = srcClone.reshape(0,samples.rows);

//Convert to algorithm friendly CV_32F
samples.convertTo(samples, CV_32F);

//Run K-Means for MAX_ITER times
for (int clusterCount = 0; clusterCount < ImageSegment::MAX_ITER; clusterCount++)
{
    compactness[clusterCount] = kmeans(samples, clusters, labels[clusterCount], TermCriteria( CV_TERMCRIT_EPS+CV_TERMCRIT_ITER, 10, 1.0), 5, KMEANS_PP_CENTERS, centres);

    cout << "COM: " << compactness[clusterCount] << endl;

    //Increment cluster (k++)
    clusters++;
    centresVector[clusterCount] = centres;
}

//Reconstruct the processed image
vector<Mat> temp(3);
Mat tempMerged;
int *labelPtr;

//Reassign all of 'temp' to zeros
for (int q = 0; q < 3; q++)
{
    temp[q] = Mat::zeros(samples.rows, 1, CV_8UC1);
}

for (int r = 0; r < ImageSegment::MAX_ITER; r++)
{
    //Final output image is 3-channel dimension(src)
    ImageSegment::Image[r] = Mat::zeros(src.rows, src.cols, CV_8UC3);
    labelPtr = labels[r].data();
    centres = centresVector[r];

    for (int x = 0; x <= samples.rows; x++)
    {
        temp[0].at<float>(x,0) = centres.at<float>(*labelPtr,0);
        temp[1].at<float>(x,1) = centres.at<float>(*labelPtr,1);
        temp[2].at<float>(x,2) = centres.at<float>(*labelPtr,2);
        ++labelPtr;
    }

    tempMerged = Mat::zeros(src.rows, src.cols, src.type());
    merge(temp, tempMerged);
    ImageSegment::Image[r] = tempMerged.reshape(0,src.rows);
}

return compactness;
```

}

Comment: Change `vector<int> kmeansSegmentation(Mat src)`  to `vector<int> ImageSegment::kmeansSegmentation(Mat src)` you are declaring a free function `kmeansSegmentation(Mat src)` that has nothing to do with your class.

Comment: @drescherjm Im so stupid, thank you so much :) but I get no viable overload '=', when trying to initialise ImageSegment::Image as but I get no viable overload '=', when trying to initialise ImageSegment::Image as           `ImageSegment::Image[r] = Mat::zeros(src.rows, src.cols, CV_8UC3);`. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

For 1), they syntax you used was to access static member, but Image is a non-static data member. You'd instead create an object of type ImageSegment, and then access its Image data member:

```
ImageSegment seg;
seg.Image[r] = Mat::zeros(src.rows, src.cols, CV_8UC3);
seg.Image[r] = tempMerged.reshape(0, src.rows);
```

For 2), a common coding pattern is to put data member in private and use an accessor for it:

```
class ImageSegment {
 private:
  ...
  int minCluster_;  // note the trailing underscore

 public:
  ImageSegment();
  ...
  int minCluster() const { return minCluster_; }
  ...
};
```

Then you could initialize another variable like:

```
ImageSegment seg;
... // do something about seg
int clusters = seg.minCluster();
```

Comment: Thank you @Edy, but i found the solution from the comment above :)